# How to use Selenium click element with Beautiful soup

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

My question has two folds:

1. I am trying to extract the read more section from trip advisor hotel reviews. My code seems to work, i.e expands the read more button but then it keeps getting this error - "StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"
   Could you please help me? can't figure out why

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

url = "https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Hotel_Review-g186338-d187591-Reviews-The_Ritz_London-London_England"
driver.get(url)
try:
    buttons = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='_3maEfNCR']")))
except:
    pass
else:
    for button in buttons:
        button.click()
```

2. I would like beautiful soup to take the page source from the above script to extract the relevant information from the page.
   I tried the following code but it's not working because of the above staleelementreference error.
   Can you spot what I might be doing wrong here please?

```
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
for review_container in soup.find_all('div', class_= '_2wrUUKlw _3hFEdNs8'):
    review_title = review_container.find('div', class_= 'glasR4aX').text
    print (review_title)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below approach.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

url = "https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Hotel_Review-g186338-d187591-Reviews-The_Ritz_London-London_England"
driver.get(url)
try:
    buttons = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='_3maEfNCR']")))
except:
    pass
else:
    for i in range(len(buttons)):
        driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('_3maEfNCR')[arguments[0]].click()", i)
```

Comment: Thanks you, but I'm still getting the same error @Dilip

Comment: Code updated check now. There is a strange behavior with website if you click on the first `Read More` is expanding the section for all 5 elements.